# When select is faster than a for?

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate, jpa

Imagine the situation, I have an Id of an Entity and I have a liked list with some entities of the same class. To find the the entity, when is faster do a for in the linked list or do a select at the database?

I mean, when I have about 5 entities in a linked list, for example, I imagine that a for is faster, and when I have millions of entities the select will be faster.

But when the select starts to be faster than the for?

Comment: The fastest seems to be to use the non-standard recursive select mechanism of the underlying database (e.g. common table expressions with SQLServer). Not sure hibernate can be rigged to make use of that though.

Comment: There are in-memory data structures that work better than scanning a list.  In fact, your database library ultimately is going to end up using some algorithm that you could have used directly in your code.

Comment: Why would you ever have millions of entities in memory, in a linked list? I can't imagine a single good reason to be in such a situation. In general, doing a few tests against objects loaded in memory is muuuuch faster tha executing a SQL query over a database, over the network, or at least across separate processes. It might not be true for millions of entities (because the database could use an index that finds the row faster than by iterating), but that should never happen anyway.

Comment: Linked list is one of the slowest kind of collection to do search, I was just thinking in the worst case. But the real situation is a faces component that have a list of entities. In my converter I can find through this list or search at the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is faster after 1e5 elements on my machine*.
Baseline for selecting from table with one record trough jpa is 1ms.

> Confidence interval (99.9%): [0,747, 1,087]

Select from 1e5 records will take the same time(1ms) lower bound increase by 0.1ms.

Sequential search in list of 1e5 elements where desired element placed last takes 2ms.

> Confidence interval (99.9%): [2073669,347, 2514442,020]

Ammortize this dividing by two for the random postition of desired element.

FYI getting entity from the map of 1e5 elements will take less than 30ns

Here is my benchmark for peer review:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf;
List<Individual> list;
Map<Integer, Individual> map;

@Setup
public void setUp() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("postgres");
    list = new ArrayList<Individual>();
    map = new HashMap<Integer, Individual>();

    for (int i = (int)1e5; i > 0; i--) {
        Individual individual = new Individual(i);
        list.add(individual);
        map.put(i, individual);
    }
}

@TearDown
public void tearDown() {
    emf.close();
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public Individual measureJpa() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Query query = em.createQuery("select i from com.company.Individual i where i.id = 1");

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Individual individual = (Individual) query.getSingleResult();

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.close();

    return individual;
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public Individual measureList() {
    for (Individual i : list) {
        if (i.id == 1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public Individual measureMap() {
    return map.get(1);
}
```

- Dual core 1.5GHz CPU, 7200rmp HDD, 600MHz RAM, Windows 7 x64, JDK 1.8.0_05, EclipseLink 2.5.1, PostgesSql 9.3

Answer (score 5):

An in-memory data structure is always faster than opening a socket, running a query and sending back a response.

A good query may run in 10-100ms, while a Java operation might take 100ns.

Using a LinkedList might not yield the best performance. Analogue to using a database index, you can use a HashMap instead, and map entities by their ids:

```
Map<Long, Entity> idEntityMap = new HashMap<>;
idEntityMap.put(entity.getId(), entity);
```

So when you search for an entity you simply run:

```
Entity entity = idEntityMap.get(entityId);
```

The call will first identify the Map bucket, where the entity reside and only do an object comparison for the entities contained in that bucket.

All in all, in-memory operations are very fast, but you need to use a data structure that's suitable for your use case.